# MSDN code example: Why does it check null before calling static Object.Equals?

Tags: c#, equals, equality, equals-operator

In Microsoft's MSDN Library article on `IEquatable<T>.Equals` Method, (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx) an example is presented to demonstrate how to override Equals and Equality operator. It looks like this:

```
public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
   private string uniqueSsn;
   private string lName;

   public bool Equals(Person other) 
   {
      if (other == null) 
         return false;

      if (this.uniqueSsn == other.SSN)
         return true;
      else 
         return false;
   }

   public override bool Equals(Object obj)
   {
      if (obj == null) 
         return false;

      Person personObj = obj as Person;
      if (personObj == null)
         return false;
      else    
         return Equals(personObj);   
   }   

   public static bool operator == (Person person1, Person person2)
   {
      if ((object)person1 == null || ((object)person2) == null) // Here !!!
         return Object.Equals(person1, person2);

      return person1.Equals(person2);
   }
   ...
}
```

My attention was drawn to this line: `if ((object)person1 == null || ((object)person2) == null)      return Object.Equals(person1, person2);`

To my understanding, static Object.Equals would auto check null for its parameters. Why does it bother checking null again before calling it? Is there a guideline for doing it?

I would implement it simply like this:

```
   public static bool operator == (Person person1, Person person2)
   {
         return Object.Equals(person1, person2);
   }
```

Or maybe this:

```
   public static bool operator == (Person person1, Person person2)
   {
      if ((object)person1 == null)
         return ((object)person2 == null)

      return person1.Equals(person2);
   }
```

Based on this quote from the same document: "If you do override `Object.Equals(Object)`, your overridden implementation is also called in calls to the `static Equals(System.Object, System.Object)` method on your class"

#### Update:

I found a possible error in `public bool Equals(Person other)`, it reads: `other == null` where `==` is overloaded! Although the result is correct, there is an extra level of indirection. I believe it should be `(object)other == null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach would end up invoking the *virtual* `Equals(Object)` method, because that's what `Object.Equals` does. The way that's given here only uses `Object.Equals` when at least one of the values is null, in order to return `true` if they're both null and false otherwise - that path will never call back into your `Equals` implementations.

If both values are non-null, the MSDN approach will make a *non-virtual* call straight to `bool Equals(Person)` - which avoids not only a virtual method indirection, but also another type check which is redundant when we already know that if the references *are* non-null, they're both `Person` references.

I think the example is unfortunate in its mixture of using fields and properties, mind you - and I'd definitely write this:

```
if (this.uniqueSsn == other.SSN)
   return true;
else 
   return false;
```

as just:

```
return this.uniqueSsn == other.SSN;
```

or more obviously:

```
return this.uniqueSsn == other.uniqueSsn;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I had thought. But i doubted myself as it seems `static Object.Equals` is called only for a small/minor part of its functional, which I feel strange. Anyway, is my 2nd implementation correct?

Comment: @colinfang: Yes, that would work. I think I prefer the simplicity of the MSDN approach of getting rid of any possibility of nullity up-front, but your second approach should be fine.

Comment: I found a possible error in `public bool Equals(Person other)`, it reads: `other == null` where `==` is overloaded! Although the result is correct, there is an extra level of indirection. I believe it should be `(object)other == null`.

Comment: @colinfang: I wouldn't call that an *error*, but yes - I agree it would be better using the cast.